# How Do I post alarm notfication to an application using any interface(other tahn smtp) in thingsboard.io

Tags: thingsboard

I want to send alarm notification to an external application . I saw the user guide to send alarm notification to email via SMTP . I need to know how can I configure an application so that the alarm can be sent over http/tcp.

Thanks
skp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Thingsboards rule-chain for this.

There is a rule-node called `rest api call` where you can setup the request.
It will send the message payload of its input as the request body.